# Getting error while mirgating the project

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-artisan, migrate

I tried to migrate the project but got an error

php artisan migrate

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user 'api'@'localhost' to database 'api' (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = api and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:801
    797▕                     $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    798▕                 );
    799▕             }
    800▕
  ➜ 801▕             throw new QueryException(
    802▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    803▕             );
    804▕         }
    805▕     }

  1   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:65
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user 'api'@'localhost' to database 'api'")

  2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:65
      PDO::__construct()
```

Connection to mysql with login and password from .env is working

Paste "extension=pdo_mysql" in php.ini is also not working

Comment: `Access denied` either means bad user/pass combination, or `api@localhost` doesn't have access to the database `api`

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that the user 'api' does not have the necessary privileges to access the 'api' database or the 'migrations' table within it. This issue can occur when the user specified in the database configuration does not have the appropriate permissions.
To resolve:

1. Verify the correctness of the database credentials.
2. Grant necessary privileges to the user
3. After granting the privileges, execute the command "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;" to ensure the changes take effect.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a difference between the way you connect to the database and the way Laravel is attempting to connect to it.

You will need to make sure that you are using the same username and password.

Also, you will need to make sure that your "normal" connection and Laravel tries to connect through the same port.

If ssh is involved, then you will need to make sure that it is properly set.

Finally, it's possible that your api user does not have the necessary privileges to the api database from the source where Laravel attempts to run it. You will need to make sure that you grant the necessary privileges to your api user in the context of the host Laravel is connecting from.

Answer (score -1):

Verify the user api:

- the password is correct?
- user has permission to schema api and information_schema?

Answer (score -1):

Issue: Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user 'api'@'localhost' to database 'api'

Solution:

This error indicates that the user 'api' does not have sufficient privileges to access the database 'api'. To resolve this issue, follow these steps:

1. Check Database Credentials: Verify that the database credentials in your .env file are correct. Ensure that **DB_DATABASE**, **DB_USERNAME**, and **DB_PASSWORD** are set appropriately.
2. Database User Privileges: Make sure that the database user specified in your .env file has the necessary privileges to access the 'api' database. You can do this by logging into your MySQL or MariaDB server using a tool like phpMyAdmin or the MySQL command-line interface and granting the required privileges to the user.

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON api.* TO 'api'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Replace '**api**' with your actual database username and '**localhost**' with your host if it's different.

After making changes, try reconnecting to the database to ensure that the issue is resolved.